# SubscriptBox Text font in Graphics[Text[Style["..."]]]

Tags: graphics, style, text, fonts, subscript

In this code in Graphics and Text Style,

```
Graphics[Text[
```

Style["!(N_b)\n U(1!(*SubscriptBox[()), (V)])"]]]

I obtain the $V$ in italic font,

[image]

but I wanted to have a text font like V, like this

[image].

**How should I do to make V in the text font in the SubscriptBox?**

Thank you in advance for your input! Any comment can be upgraded to be an answer! Please.

Comment: Just to add more info - your `Style` expression formats in an upright font outside of a Graphics, but is italic inside the Graphics.

Comment: Should the $N_b$ remain italicized?  By default text in graphics formats in TraditionalForm, which is what's causing the italics.  Setting `FormatType` would change that, but affect the other parts some.

Comment: Yes $N_b$ remains italicized - that was what I wanted to keep.

Comment: I only what to change the subscript from $V$ to text V.

Comment: How about: `Graphics[Text[Row[{Subscript[N, b],Subscript[U[1], "V"]}]]]`?

Comment: Thanks - that helps - but there is also a changing of row in my case -- I updated - there was a "\n" for me to change row, are you able to change row, too?

Comment: You can use `Graphics[Text[Column[{Subscript[N, b], Subscript[U[1], "V"]}, Alignment -> Center]]]` to have them in a column. Or `Graphics[Text[Column[{Subscript[N, b], Subscript[U[1], Style[V, Plain]]}, Alignment -> Center]]]` if you don't want to use a string.